# How can I add url parameter to a specific path in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have configured a path for google maps. Then I require it few times in different places. And I want to pass a language parameter to the url to load correct localization. Is it possible?

For example:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        module: 'lib/module',
        gmaps: 'http://GOOGLE_MAPS_URL'
    }
});

require(['module', 'async!gmaps' + '&language=pt-BR'], function() {});
```

Comment: Did you try it? What results did you get?

Comment: @Louis there is an error. Because it tries to load ''async!gmaps&language=pt-BR', and there is no such module *gmaps&language=pt-BR*.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I found solution for me. I created a module that returns a function that returns correct url depending on provided language:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        module: 'lib/module',
        getGmapsUrl: 'lib/getGmapsUrl'
    }
});
```

And then in lib/getGmapsUrl.js:

```
define('getGmapsUrl', function () {
    var gmapsBaseUrl = 'async!http://GOOGLE_MAPS_URL';
    return function (lang) {
        return gmapsBaseUrl + '&language=' + lang;
    };
});
```

And the I use it like this:

```
require(['module', 'getGmapsUrl'], function (module, getGmapsUrl) {
    var gmapsUrl = getGmapsUrl('pt-BR'); // 'async!http://GOOGLE_MAPS_URL&language=pt-BR'
    require([gmapsUrl], function () {
        // here I have correct localization for google maps
    });
});
```

It works, but it is not a very beautiful solution.